# ASP.Net MVC3 gives me an exception if I rename a parameter from id to albumId

Tags: model, view, asp.net-mvc-3, controller

I'm following along the ASP.Net MVC3 application Music Store and I've noticed this.

Here is my Details action in the Store controller.

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    var album = new Album() { Title = "Dark Side of The Moon" + id };
    return View(album);
}

//View
@model MvcMusicStore.Models.Album

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>Album Name: @Model.Title</h2>
```

It works fine, however when I tried to change the parameter name from "id" to "albumId" I get the following error:

> The parameters dictionary contains a
>   null entry for parameter 'albumid' of
>   non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for
>   method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult
>   Details(Int32)' in
>   'MvcMusicStore.Controllers.StoreController'.
>   An optional parameter must be a
>   reference type, a nullable type, or be
>   declared as an optional parameter.
>   Parameter name: parameters

Why does having a variable with a certain name work, but with another name it produces this error? Does MVC do something automagically with variables names "id"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your routing configuration likely has {controller}/{action}/{id}, where it should have {controller}/{action}/{albumid}

Look in your global.asax

Comment: Yes that's correct. Here's what I have in my global.asax. Does that mean that if I want to use albumId as the parameter, I **must** create a new route for the Store controller? http://pastebin.com/BPJLve07

Comment: Yes, you must have a route that matches the parameter names of your actions.